# advanced T.type_parameter usage in Sorbet

Tags: sorbet

To write generic methods, I only found [this example on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20Box%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%20%20Elem%20%3D%20type_member%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(x%3A%20Elem).void%7D%0A%20%20def%20initialize(x)%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%3Dx%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%20do%0A%20%20%20%20type_parameters(%3AU)%0A%20%20%20%20.params(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20blk%3A%20T.proc.params(arg0%3A%20Elem).returns(T.type_parameter(%3AU))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20%20%20.returns(Box%5BT.type_parameter(%3AU)%5D)%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20def%20map(%26blk)%0A%20%20%20%20Box.new(blk.call(%40x))%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0ABox%5BInteger%5D.new(0).map(%26%3Asucc).map(%26%3Afoo)).
[sorbet.org/docs](https://sorbet.org/docs) doesn't mention `type_parameter` currently. So I got a few questions about the advanced usage of `T.type_parameter`.

1. Restrict parent type

How can I specify, that only subtypes of a certain type are allowed? (same for generic classes, using `type_member`)
E.g. only "Enumerable" types are allowed, so I can call all the stuff from "Enumerable" on that object.

2. factory methods

I've a method which instantiates an object of a given class. (e.g. because it's using parameters which shall be kept private). How can I write a signature for that?

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23typed%3A%20true%0A%0Aclass%20Animal%0A%20%20def%20initialize(secret_of_nature)%3B%20end%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20Sidewinder%20%3C%20Animal%0A%20%20def%20rattle%3B%20end%0Aend%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Nature%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(animal_cls%3A%20T.class_of(Animal)).returns(Animal)%7D%0A%20%20def%20self.factory(animal_cls)%0A%20%20%20%20animal_cls.new(%40secret_dna)%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0A%0ANature%3A%3Afactory(Sidewinder).rattle%0A%23%20%3D%3E%20Method%20rattle%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20Animal)

```
#typed: true

class Animal
  def initialize(secret_of_nature); end
end

class Sidewinder < Animal
  def rattle; end
end


class Nature
  extend T::Sig

  sig {params(animal_cls: T.class_of(Animal)).returns(Animal)}
  def self.factory(animal_cls)
    animal_cls.new(@secret_dna)
  end
end


Nature::factory(Sidewinder).rattle
# => Method rattle does not exist on Animal
```

Comment: I think you've posted your solution into another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454717/syntax-for-methods-using-raise-throw-in-sorbet

Comment: Indeed... just copied it here.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found the answer for "1. Restrict parent type".

Nevertheless, I'm still missing a solution for "2. factory methods".
Especially how to specify the return value by the generic type of the given class.

---

Answer: 1. Restrict parent type

It's in the commit log just five days ago.

[Add type bounds to generics (#1392)](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/commit/417c1087dc3a5f76665fc49459b85c297e1ffac4)

Looks like `lower` can also be omitted.

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0A%0Aclass%20Animal%3B%20end%0Aclass%20Cat%20%3C%20Animal%3B%20end%0Aclass%20Serval%20%3C%20Cat%3B%20end%0A%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%20%20T1%20%3D%20type_member(lower%3A%20Serval%2C%20upper%3A%20Animal)%0Aend%0A%0A%23%20should%20pass%3A%20Cat%20is%20within%20the%20bounds%20of%20T1%0Aclass%20B1%20%3C%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%20%20T1%20%3D%20type_member(fixed%3A%20Cat)%0Aend%0A%0A%23%20should%20fail%3A%20String%20is%20not%20within%20the%20bounds%0Aclass%20B2%20%3C%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%20%20T1%20%3D%20type_member(fixed%3A%20String)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%20error%3A%20parent%20lower%20bound%20%60Serval%60%20is%20not%20a%20subtype%20of%20lower%20bound%20%60String%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%20error%3A%20upper%20bound%20%60String%60%20is%20not%20a%20subtype%20of%20parent%20upper%20bound%20%60Animal%60%0Aend%0A%0A%23%20should%20pass%3A%20the%20bounds%20are%20a%20refinement%20of%20the%20ones%20on%20A%0Aclass%20C1%20%3C%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%20%20T1%20%3D%20type_member(lower%3A%20Serval%2C%20upper%3A%20Cat)%0Aend%0A%0A%23%20should%20fail%3A%20the%20bounds%20are%20wider%20than%20on%20A%0Aclass%20C2%20%3C%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%20%20T1%20%3D%20type_member(lower%3A%20Serval%2C%20upper%3A%20Object)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%20error%3A%20upper%20bound%20%60Object%60%20is%20not%20a%20subtype%20of%20parent%20upper%20bound%20%60Animal%60%0Aend%0A%0A%23%20should%20fail%3A%20the%20implicit%20bounds%20of%20top%20and%20bottom%20are%20too%20wide%20for%20T1%0Aclass%20D1%20%3C%20A%0A%20%20T1%20%3D%20type_member%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%20error%3A%20parent%20lower%20bound%20%60Serval%60%20is%20not%20a%20subtype%20of%20lower%20bound%20%60T.noreturn%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%20error%3A%20upper%20bound%20%60%3Cany%3E%60%20is%20not%20a%20subtype%20of%20parent%20upper%20bound%20%60Animal%60%0Aend%0A)

```
# typed: true

class Animal; end
class Cat < Animal; end
class Serval < Cat; end

class A
  extend T::Generic
  T1 = type_member(lower: Serval, upper: Animal)
end

# should pass: Cat is within the bounds of T1
class B1 < A
  extend T::Generic
  T1 = type_member(fixed: Cat)
end

# should fail: String is not within the bounds
class B2 < A
  extend T::Generic
  T1 = type_member(fixed: String)
     # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: parent lower bound `Serval` is not a subtype of lower bound `String`
     # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: upper bound `String` is not a subtype of parent upper bound `Animal`
end

# should pass: the bounds are a refinement of the ones on A
class C1 < A
  extend T::Generic
  T1 = type_member(lower: Serval, upper: Cat)
end

# should fail: the bounds are wider than on A
class C2 < A
  extend T::Generic
  T1 = type_member(lower: Serval, upper: Object)
     # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error: upper bound `Object` is not a subtype of parent upper bound `Animal`
end

# should fail: the implicit bounds of top and bottom are too wide for T1
class D1 < A
  T1 = type_member
     # ^^^^^^^^^^^ error: parent lower bound `Serval` is not a subtype of lower bound `T.noreturn`
     # ^^^^^^^^^^^ error: upper bound `<any>` is not a subtype of parent upper bound `Animal`
end
```

https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/417c1087dc3a5f76665fc49459b85c297e1ffac4/test/testdata/infer/generics/bounds_super.rb