# syntax for methods using raise / throw in Sorbet

Tags: sorbet

Is there a way to specify which exceptions a method might `raise`, so it's known for which a `rescue` might be needed?

In Java ([Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html)) it looks this way:

```
void example(int: x) throws Exception {
  if x > 42 throw new Exception;
}
```

Maybe something like this!?

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7Bparams(x%3A%20Integer).void.raises(StandardError)%7D%0Adef%20example(x)%0A%20%20raise%20RuntimeError%20if%20x%20%3E%2042%0Aend)

```
# typed: true
extend T::Sig

sig {params(x: Integer).void.raises(StandardError)}
def example(x)
  raise RuntimeError if x > 42
end
```

Don't get confused: Usual exceptions are handled using `raise ... rescue` in Ruby.

```
begin
  raise StandardError
rescue StandardError
end
```

But you can also `throw` objects and `catch` them in Ruby.

```
catch(:something) do
  throw :something
end
```

I don't use this a lot. Actually trying to avoid it totally. But Sorbet might also have a syntax for this!? E.g.:

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20%7Bparams(x%3A%20Integer).void.throws(%3Asomething)%7D%0Adef%20example(x)%0A%20%20throw%20%3Asomething%20if%20x%20%3E%2042%0Aend%0A%0Acatch%20(%3Asomething)%20%7Bexample(42)%7D)

```
# typed: true
extend T::Sig

sig {params(x: Integer).void.throws(:something)}
def example(x)
  throw :something if x > 42
end

catch (:something) {example(42)}
```

Comment: Jez on the Sorbet team at Stripe has a great blog post about checked exceptions, namely why Sorbet doesn't have them and how you can use union types to model your control flow: https://blog.jez.io/union-types-checked-exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

Sorbet does not support checked exceptions.
The reason for that is that it's generally agreed between people working on Java today that they don't work well with other features of even Java. For example, in the snippet below

```
foo do
  # code that calls into something that can throw
end
```

In Java you are formally forced to catch exceptions inside `#` and rethrow them as unchecked one, as in general the block might escape to heap.
Overall, if you look into languages that followed Java: Scala, Kotlin, neither of them supports checked exceptions.